# Azure Terraform initial setup

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I worked with Terraform for AWS before successfully. Now I am trying to work with Azure and facing a few challenges. I have successfully authenticated to my azure account using Azure CLI. When I run the basic terraform provider arm .tf and do a terraform init it just works. But when I put in any additional code like container creation or blob creation .tfs, the init is not working and is giving me the below message :

No available provider "azure" plugins are compatible with this Terraform version.

> Error: no available version is compatible with this version of Terraform

Terraform version :

```
bash-3.2$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.19
+ provider.azurerm v1.38.0
```

I used version 1.38.0 and tried many others but it still continues to give me error.

Comment: What does your Terraform code look like?

Comment: bash-3.2$ cat main.tf
provider "azurerm" {
 version = "~> 1.27"
}

bash-3.2$ cat container.tf
resource "azure_storage_container" "stor-cont" {
  name                  = "terraform-storage-container"
  container_access_type = "blob"
  storage_service_name  = "abcycentralstorage"
}

Comment: You should have edited your question to include it with formatted code blocks. But it's a simple typo anyway. That should be `azurerm_storage_container`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Changing the resource from azure_storage_container to azurerm_storage_container made it work. Also there was another change that I had to do - from 'storage_service_name' to 'storage_account_name'.

Comment: A quick follow up to the above is that I got the template from the below location : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/r/storage_container.html but it appears the syntax when using azurerm is different. Is there someplace else that I should be looking for to get the accurate syntax ?

Comment: In other words, the difference between the below 2 sources of documentation or terraform links : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/r/storage_blob.html#type vs https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_blob.html

Answer (score 1):

They are the two providers for the different Azure models.

[Azure Service Management Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/index.html) model is the classic model in Azure and is not recommended to use now. It provides the resources with format `azure_xxx`.

[Azure Resource Manager Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html) model is the Resource Manager model which calls ARM and is recommended to use and supported well. It provides the resources with format `azurerm_xxx`.

You can also learn more about the ASM and ARM model in document [Azure Resource Manager vs. classic deployment: Understand deployment models and the state of your resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models).

Comment: @azdevad1 That's great, then you can accept it as the answer.